# How to correctly query list in firebase/angularfire?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have this structure:

[image]

I found this: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/4-querying-lists.md and also I read firebase docs.

I try this:

```
return this.db.list(`${this.API_EVENTS_PATH}`, {
  query: {
    equalTo: {
      value: 'sharikov.vladislav@gmail.com',
      key: 'from'
    }
  }
});
```

This gives nothing: empty array. Why?

And another question is: how to I can filter items by 2 fields? I need `from=sharikov.vladislav@gmail.com&status=ACCEPTED` for example.

How it is possible to do it with FB?

Answer (score 2):

> For your first question.

Before you use the EqualTo filter there should first be an OrderBy filter... This OrderBy filter tells the query which field should EqualTo refer to... So your query should look like this.

```
let path = this.API_EVENTS_PATH;
return db.list(path , {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'from',
    equalTo: 'sharikov.vladislav@gmail.com',
  }
});
```

> For your second question

**How to filter items by 2 fields**

In Nosql database like firebase you are normally allowed to filter by only 1 field. Every other manipulations are done considering on how you organise your database. Check out this firebase [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKFLI5FOOHs) which shows you how to do your normal SQL queries on firebase database. Enjoy

Comment: "In Nosql database like firebase you are normally allowed to filter by only 1 field" There are plenty of NoSQL databases that allow filtering on multiple properties.. This is just a Firebase limitation. I'd also recommend reading my answer on filtering on multiple values here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase, which covers a few more scenarios than David's video.